# Why does using Validators.compose change return type of FormControl?

Tags: typescript, validation, reactive, formgroups

I noticed that when using Validators.compose, the return type of a string FormControl is "string | null".

Eg:

```
text: ['', Validators.compose([
  Validators.required,
  Validators.maxLength(8),
  Validators.pattern(RegistrationValidationRegex.LETTERS_NUMBERS)
])],
```

Will return `string | null`, but

```
text: ['', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.maxLength(8),
  Validators.pattern(RegistrationValidationRegex.LETTERS_NUMBERS)
]]
```

Will return `string`. This creates problems for me when attempting to assign `formGroup.getRawValue()` to a type, as I have to adjust the property types to `string | null`.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Not sure why the difference, but you may want to make the control `nonNullable` anyway, if you don't want it to be `null`.

Comment: @Blackhole It being null is not a concern. I'm just curious how to overcome having to change all of my type properties return types to x | null etc.